# Pandas formatting column within DataFrame and adding timedelta Index error

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to use panda to do some analysis on some messaging data and am running into a few problems try to prep the data. It is coming from a database I don't have control of and therefore I need to do a little pruning and formatting before analyzing it.

Here is where I'm at so far:

```
#select all the messages in the database. Be careful if you get the whole test data base, may have 5000000 messages.
full_set_data = pd.read_sql("Select * from message",con=engine)
```

After I make this change to the timestamp, and set it as index, I'm no longer and to call to_csv.

```
#convert timestamp to a timedelta and set as index
#full_set_data[['timestamp']] = full_set_data[['timestamp']].astype(np.timedelta64)
indexed = full_set_data.set_index('timestamp')
indexed.to_csv('indexed.csv')

#extract the data columns I really care about since there as a bunch I don't need
datacolumns = indexed[['address','subaddress','rx_or_tx', 'wordcount'] + [col for col in indexed.columns if ('DATA' in col)]]
```

Here I need to format the DATA columns, I get a "SettingWithCopyWarning".

```
#now need to format the DATA columns to something useful by removing the upper 4 bytes
for col in datacolumns.columns:
  if 'DATA' in col:
    datacolumns[col] = datacolumns[col].apply(lambda x : int(x,16) & 0x0000ffff)

datacolumns.to_csv('data_col.csv')


#now group the data by "interaction key"
groups = datacolumns.groupby(['address','subaddress','rx_or_tx'])
```

I need to figure out how to get all the messages from a given group. get_group() requires I know key values ahead of time.

```
key_group = groups.get_group((1,1,1))
#foreach group in groups:
  #do analysis
```

I have tried everything I could think of to fix the problems I'm running into but I cant seem to get around it. I'm sure it's from me misunderstanding/misusing Pandas as I'm still figuring it out.

I looking to solve these issues:

1) Can't save to csv after I add index of timestamp as timedelta64

2) How do I apply a function to a set of columns to remove SettingWithCopyWarning when reformatting DATA columns.

3) How to grab the rows for each group without having to use get_group() since I don't know the keys ahead of time.

Thanks for any insight and help so I can better understand how to properly use Pandas.

Comment: If the 'timestamp' column contains a date and time, why are converting it to a timedelta64 dtype? Time deltas represent differences between dates and times.

Comment: it contains the ns since recording started. I tried to get it to a timedate but it didn't want to parse correctly. I though it would just be 'ns' for the format but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you can set the index column(s) and parse dates while querying the DB:

```
indexed = pd.read_sql_query("Select * from message", engine=engine,
                            parse_dates='timestamp', index_col='timestamp')
```

Note I've used `pd.read_sql_query` here rather than `pd.read_sql`, which is deprecated, I think.

SettingWithCopy warning is due to the fact that `datacolumns` is a view of `indexed`, i.e. a subset of it's rows /columns, not an object in it's own right. Check out this part of the docs: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

One way to get around this is to define

```
datacolumns = indexed[<cols>].copy()
```

Another would to do

```
indexed = indexed[<cols>]
```

which effectively removes the columns you don't want, if you're happy that you won't need them again. You can then manipulate `indexed` at your leisure.
As for the groupby, you could introduce a columns of tuples which would be the group keys:

```
indexed['interaction_key'] = zip(indexed[['address','subaddress','rx_or_tx']]
indexed.groupby('interaction_key').apply(
           lambda df: some_function(df.interaction_key, ...)
```

I'm not sure if it's all exactly what you want but let me know and I can edit.

Comment: THANKS SO MUCH! That helped me clean up a bunch of stuff. For the grouping, I need to generate a bunch of plots and other analysis so I don't think that will exactly work. I need to basically find a way (or better understandy the groupby function more likely) that I can make a a for loop over each of the groups. Does that make sense?

Comment: Figured it out by RTFM...Thanks again for your help.